# MVC 4 Ajax and jquery's slidetoggle after form post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a couple of issues with MVC 4 and Ajax.

My View is very basic:

```
<div id="sName">
    @Html.Partial("PartialName", Model)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").selectpicker({ style: 'btn', menuStyle: 'dropdown' }); // I use a Bootstrap mod
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Partial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateProfile", "Account", new { form = "name" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "sName", OnSuccess = "NameUpdated", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    <span>Name</span>
    <div id="field-name">
        <a id="edit-name" href="#" title="Click here to update your name">@Model.User.Firstname @Model.User.Middlename @Model.User.Surname</a>
    </div>
    <div id="field-edit-name" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="@Model.User.Firstname" />
        <input type="text" name="middlename" value="@Model.User.Middlename" /></div>
        <input type="text" name="surname" value="@Model.User.Surname" />
        <button>Save</button>
        <button id="cancel-name">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("select").selectpicker({ style: 'btn', menuStyle: 'dropdown' });
            $("#edit-name, #cancel-name").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#field-edit-name").slideToggle(450);
                $("#field-name").slideToggle(450);
            })
        function NameUpdated() {
            $("#field-edit-name").slideToggle(450);
            $("#field-name").slideToggle(450);
        }
    </script>
}
```

And here is my Account Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel Model = new MyModel();
    return View(Model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateProfile(string form, FormCollection c)
{
    switch (form)
    {
        case "name":
            // Update name and Model
            return PartialView("PartialName", Model);
        case "email":
            // Update email and Model
            return PartialView("PartialEmail", Model);
        case "address":
            // Update address and Model
            return PartialView("PartialAddress", Model);
        default :
            break;
    }
    return View();
}
```

The first problem is: I'm calling the JQuery function "$("select").selectpicker({ style: 'btn', menuStyle: 'dropdown' });" in the View because I'll be using many Bootstrap selects (all in different Partial Views) and it makes sense to have it in one place only. However, what I'm finding is that after the Ajax postback in the Partial View above, the Bootstrap styles are lost and the select elements revert back to standard browser selects. To get around this I have

```
$(function () {
    $("select").selectpicker({ style: 'btn', menuStyle: 'dropdown' });
```

in the partial view too. This is not ideal, so is there a better way of keeping the selects styled to Bootstrap after an Ajax postback without having to repeat code?

The second problem is: When a user clicks on the link with id="edit-name", the div with id="field-name" slides out and the form fields (inside the div with id="field-edit-name") slides in. This works great. However, when the save button is clicked I want the form fields to slide back in and the link to slide back out. I thought the Ajax option OnSuccess="NameUpdated" would do it but it seems like the Ajax postback is refreshing the Partial View (making the fields abruptly disappear and the link reappear, as though the page had been refreshed). I know that Ajax is working as it should because the scroll position on the page is not lost. What am I doing wrong?

I have referenced the following JS files in the Layout page:

```
<script src="/common/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/jquery.stacktable.js"></script>
<script src="/common/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you could look at possibly having custom event, that is trigged when the partial view is loaded.

In the view you could have something like

```
$("#sName").on("customevent",function(){ //apply style here etc.... });
```

In the partial view script you could have something like

```
$("#sName").trigger("customevent");
```

For the second problem, I would suggest overriding the submit of the form, so that you can have full control on what happens.

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
             //Successful post, do work.
            }
        });
}
```